# Cannot connect to webservice using the ip address but works with 127.0.0.1

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, network-programming, ports

Currently I have webservice using dnx hosted on a specific ip address and connecting to it works fine. The service is listening at port 5004 so inorder to connect to it I use the following format

```
http://192.X.X.12:5004/api/somePar/?...
```

Now I moved the webservice to Azure and I use the following address to Remote Desktop onto the virtual machine on which it is hosted.

```
http://MyLink.cloudapp.net:54254
```

Now I am attempting to connect to it using its web address.Inside the virtual machine where the weservice is hosted if I type

```
http://127.0.0.1:5004/api/somePar/?..  (WORKS)
```

The above works. The ipconfig of the machine gives me say A.B.C.D. If I use that as such it fails.

```
http://A.B.C.D:5004/api/somePar/?..
```

I guess that is another reason why my other machines cant connect to the webservice hosted on that machine. Any suggestions on why the ip address of the machine fails and the webservice only works with 127.0.0.1
How can I fix this ?

Comment: I am not sure, but is port 5004 opened on your machine? You can open port from windows firewall.

Comment: Firewall is totally disabled

Comment: Disabling firewall is different thing, you need to open the port. Please search once how to make inbound rules and try opening port 5004.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I checked resmon ->Network Activity->Listening Ports and it seems port 5004 is open. also it seems like inbound/outbound rules are being applied to Windows Firewall. If you have a link please let me know. From what I understand is that if I disable Firewall totally this shouldnt be a problem. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: This is running in a VM, right? If so, have you created endpoints (for classic VMs) or inbound security rules (for ARM-based VMs) to allow for inbound traffic (nothing to do with OS-level firewall)? See my ServerFault answer [here](http://serverfault.com/a/737796/99269) for more info on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

What OS is the virtual machine running?  I had this exact problem with a machine running Windows 7 Professional; apparently, if you're running Windows on that VM, it needs to be Windows Server.

Comment: That might be your problem.  I haven't tested it on Windows 10 but I wouldn't be surprised if it had the same issue for you that Windows 7 had for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the binding, it should specify **All Unassigned**.

And try changing your **port** to **80** because **5004** is Real-time Transport Protocol used by Real Time Streaming Protocol (RTSP) for Microsoft Windows Media streaming services and some other things and may be **locked**.

Comment: I changed my port to 80 now atleast I could connect to the webservice using the ipaddress inside the same computer its hosted in. However i am still having trouble connecting to webservice from outside.